# How do I draw a cube with even edges on tikz or latex in general?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Below is what I have but the edges aren't equal length, does anyone know how to fix it?[image: I added a picture of what I get from this]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm]

\node (a) at (0,0) {27\ 9\ 3};
\node [below right of=a] (b) {27\ $3^4$};
\node [below left of=a] (c) {$9^43$};
\node [below of=a] (d) {$27\ 9\ 1^3$};

\node [below of=c] (e) {$9^4\ 1^3$};
\node [below right of=c] (f) {$9^3\ 3^4$};
\node [below of=b] (g) {$27\ 3^3\ 1^3$};
\node [below of=d] (h) {$9^3\ 3^3\ 1^3$};

\draw[thick, black] (a)--(b);
\draw[thick, black] (a)--(c);
\draw[thick, black] (a)--(d);
\draw[thick, black] (c)--(e);
\draw[thick, black] (c)--(f);
\draw[thick, black] (b)--(f);
\draw[thick, black] (b)--(g);
\draw[thick, black] (e)--(h);
\draw[thick, black] (f)--(h);
\draw[thick, black] (g)--(h);
\draw[thick, black] (d)--(e);
\draw[thick, black] (d)--(g);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! You can just draw the cube in three dimensions and use an appropriate orthographic projection. The isometric view comes close to the description of "equal length" but does not really give good results in this case. So I would use a generic projection that avoids overlapping nodes. The distance between the corners in 3d is still the same, but the projection on the screen is not.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,
    pics/Numbered Cube/.style={code={
    \path  (1,1,1) node (a)  {$27\ 9\ 3$}
     (1,-1,1) node (b) {$27\ 3^4$}
     (-1,-1,1) node (c) {$9^3\ 3^4$}
     (-1,1,1) node (d) {$9^43$}
     (1,1,-1) node (e)  {$27\ 9\ 1^3$}
     (1,-1,-1) node (f) {$27\ 3^3\ 1^3$}
     (-1,-1,-1) node (g) {$9^3\ 3^3\ 1^3$}
     (-1,1,-1) node (h) {$9^4\ 1^3$};
    \draw[thick] 
        (a) edge (e) -- (b) edge (f) -- (c) edge (g) -- (d) edge (h) -- (a)
        (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- (e);
    }}]
 \begin{scope}[isometric view,local bounding box=view 1]
  \pic{Numbered Cube};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=2.5cm,3d view={-45}{20},local bounding box=view 2]
  \pic{Numbered Cube};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[xshift=5cm,3d view={-25}{20},local bounding box=view 3]
  \pic{Numbered Cube};
 \end{scope}
 \path ([yshift=-1ex]current bounding box.south) coordinate (aux);
 \path[font=\sffamily] 
  (view 1.south|-aux) node[below] {isometric view}
  (view 2.south|-aux) node[below] {tilted isometric view}
  (view 3.south|-aux) node[below] {generic view};
 \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzcd}[
every arrow/.append style={dash},
column sep=0em,
row sep=1em ,
                    ]
% diagram
    &   27\,9\,3 \ar[rr]\ar[dd] \ar[dl]
        &   & 27\,3^4 \ar[dd]\ar[ld]          \\
9^4\,3 \ar[rr,crossing over]\ar[dd]
    &   & 9^3\,3^4 &                          \\
    & 27\,9\,1^3 \ar[rr]
        &   & 27\,3^3\,1^3                    \\ 
9^4\,1^3 \ar[ur]\ar[rr]
    &   & 9^3\,3^3\,1^3\ar[uu,crossing over] \ar[ur]
            &                           \\
    \end{tikzcd}%
\end{document}
```

[image]